# Unable to view all of "How do I dismiss" (vertical page size)

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

I have a problem with the "Administration tools > flags" page.
I clicked on "How do I dismiss?", and tried to scroll down the page to read all the text, but when I did it, the page have been scrolled back to make "How do I dismiss?" visible.

My screen resolution is 1600x900, and I am using Firefox 4.

[image: Firefox screenshot]

**Update:** I am having the issue also with Safari 5, and revision 2011.4.8.5 of SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the next deploy (probably in the next 10 hours), you should be able to collapse more of the existing sections, making a bit more space. Let me know if this still doesn't help.

Comment: I still have the same problem. I notice that I don't have it when I look at the page with an iPod, but I have it on a Mac with both Safari and Firefox.

Comment: @kiamlaluno will the other sections not collapse down?

Comment: I didn't notice that the "Where should I start?" section was collapsible. If I collapse it, I can read the other section content. Still, there is the problem with the page being scrolled back. Why does this happen? Is there any JavaScript doing that? If the answer is positive, is there any reason to have such JavaScript code?

Comment: @kiamlaluno yes, the script was added to try to help keep it visible; I'm not opposed to losing that, though

Comment: It seems contradictory to keep the section title visible, when somebody is trying to read the section content; considering who is using that page, I would hope there is no need to keep the section title visible, especially when one could always see it by scrolling back the page.